# how to use d3 jetpack in iVisual or PowerBI Development

Tags: d3.js, powerbi

I find it really usefull to use [d3 jetpack](https://github.com/gka/d3-jetpack).

example, instead of using getter functions  use the nice `ƒ` helper function from the d3-jetpack and compress the code a bit:

```
var columns = [
    { head: 'Movie title', cl: 'title', html: ƒ('title') },
    { head: 'Year', cl: 'center', html: ƒ('year') },
    { head: 'Length', cl: 'center', html: ƒ('length') },
    { head: 'Budget', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('budget') },
    { head: 'Rating', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('rating') }
];
```

I have used it like so ---

```
{ head: 'ten', cl: 'num', d3: f('Name', d3.format('.1f')) }
```

[image]

Now when I use this same code in my typescript class in PowerBI visuals it returns me an error saying ---

> cannot find name ƒ

**So how can I use d3 jetpack in iVisual or in typescript!**

Comment: What happens if you use `d3.f(` instead?

Comment: @Mark it shows the same error  `cannot find name ƒ`

Comment: In `d3.f(`, that's a regular "f" not a silly stylized unicode ƒ.  `ƒ` is just an alias to `d3.f`.

Comment: @Mark thanks, but have tried both, no result, See the picture